# Salesforce trigger execution duplicate rules beta feature

Tags: trigger, order-of-execution

Can anyone shed some light on #5 from https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm that talks about execution of duplicate rules which is in beta. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 5. Executes duplicate rules, which is currently available as a beta
>      feature. If the duplicate rule identifies the record as a duplicate
>      and uses the block action, the record is not saved and no further
>      steps, such as after triggers and workflow rules, are taken.

[Duplicate Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=duplicate_rules_create.htm&language=en_US) are a new feature of SalesForce that is currently in beta testing. From the [Duplicate Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=duplicate_rules_create.htm&language=en_US) documentation:

> This release contains a beta version of Data.com Duplicate Management
>   that is production quality but has known limitations. You can provide
>   feedback and suggestions on the Salesforce Success Community. For
>   information on enabling this feature for your organization, contact
>   salesforce.com.